# What can be done for questions asking about YouTube quota? - these questions can't be solved for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

Questions made in Stack Overflow about YouTube quota are those kind of questions that can't be answered - due *it's not a programming problem*, but a *support-like* type of question.

[I posted this question on Meta Stack Overflow about this matter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401337/4092887) and following the comments on the linked question, I make the question here for more visibility Stack Exchange's CM.

Quote:

> My impression is that, users who ask about quota aren't really
> informed about the process for asking more quota and neither that
> those questions can't be answered or solved here.

Since, this is not a topic for Stack Overflow: it is possible CMs of Stack Exchange speak with YouTube/Google CMs for solve this situation?

What can be done for questions asking about YouTube quota? - in the linked question I ask for a generic answer that try to solve the problem of the OP - in a way that SO helps them - rather than just close as off-topic or any other workaround that doesn't actually help.

Comment: The solution is to ask YouTube about questions about their service, not SO. This is definitely not responsibility of CMs or anyone at SO/SE...

Comment: @BryanKrause but YouTube redirects to SO, I don't see why CMs can't or is not a responsibility for them - since this matter affects their image.

Comment: "YouTube redirects to SO" ???

Comment: @BryanKrause [yes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) - see at the end of the page

Comment: That's not SO's problem.

Comment: @BryanKrause has already said it - ask YouTube.  It isn't SO's problem.  Also, why does the link at the end of the page matter?

Comment: @Ollie it matters due OP say there were redirected/sended here (*at SO*).

Comment: Can't make every website on the internet responsible for every other website that links to them.  If YouTube doesn't want to provide proper customer service, that is their problem, they can't force SO to provide that service for them.

Comment: 'it is possible CMs of Stack Exchange speak with YouTube/Google CMs for solve this situation?', well, I suppose that might be arranged but, I have to ask, do you have any idea of how much that would cost?  Just asking for a quote from SO would be expensive, and terms would likely involve a substantial up-front deposit plus subsequent billed hours.  It's not a good plan.

Comment: @MartinJames I have no idea how much that would cost. If SE would care, they might even consider invest in this, otherwise, well, more people will keep asking for non-answerable questions.

Answer (score 9):

This would be like if you emailed companyname@gmail.com and failed to get a response, and then went to Google to complain that someone using their Gmail service didn't respond to you.

If you aren't getting the customer service you want from a company that say they will answer your question at Stack Overflow, there is nothing SE/SO can or should do about it. You will need to find another way to contact the company directly or use a different service.